# Does water exert normal force?

Tags: forces, fluid-statics

If water donot exert normal force than why? As I know normal force is due to repulsion force of electrons so why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When stationary fluids (water, air, etc) exert forces it is more common to describe them in terms of *pressures*, but it's the same phenomenon as normal force with a different mathematical approach.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, the answer is "yes".  Buoyant forces are involved when you are dealing with fluids, and those forces always act perpendicular to whatever surface they are in contact with.  However, there is a difference between normal force and buoyant force.  For a cylinder sitting on a solid surface, the normal force acts only on the bottom of the cylinder.  For a cylinder partially or totally immersed in a fluid, there are buoyant forces on all surfaces that are in that fluid (e.g., top, bottom, and sides).

Comment: Surface tension could also be considered another example of liquid normal force.